# Put text onto Image by using C or C++ without using puttext function in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, cimg, vivado-hls

does anyone know how to write a code(C/C++) to put text into images without using the puttext function in opencv? I'd been google-ing for this function for quite awhile, but didn't manage to get a solution.

Comment: a lot of people know that. what is your actual question? I doubt that this answer is what you were looking for. please read [ask] and improve your post. so you don't want to use OpenCV? what about other libraries?

Comment: What's the objection to `puttext()` exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Sorry it's my first time to post question here. As i'm trying to do image processing onto FPGA, OpenCV function cannot be accelerated using FPGA and is causing illegal memory access, thus, I need to write a C/C++ function to put text onto the image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It's slow. Try overlaying 50-100 lines on a video stream at 30fps with putText() and see for yourself.

Answer (score 5):

I commend [CImg](http://cimg.eu) to you - it is clean, modern C++ and very capable. It is very simple to integrate in a project because it is *"header only** -  just one include file and no libraries to link against.

It can read and write [NetPBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) files (PGM, PPM etc) natively without any special linking and can read and write everything else either using `libjpeg`, `libtiff`, `libpng` or **ImageMagick**.

It can also display images on X11 or on Windows via GDI, if you want it to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

int main() {
   // Create 640x480 image
   CImg<unsigned char> image(640,480,1,3);

   // Fill with magenta
   cimg_forXY(image,x,y) {
      image(x,y,0,0)=255;
      image(x,y,0,1)=0;
      image(x,y,0,2)=255;
   }

   // Make some colours
   unsigned char cyan[]    = {0,   255, 255 };
   unsigned char black[]   = {0,   0,   0   };
   unsigned char yellow[]  = {255, 255, 0   };

   // Draw black text on cyan
   image.draw_text(30,60,"Black 64pt on cyan",black,cyan,1,64);

   // Draw yellow partially transparent text on black
   image.draw_text(80,200,"Yellow 32pt on black semi-transparent",yellow,black,0.5,32);

   // Save result image as NetPBM PNM - no libraries required
   image.save_pnm("result.pnm");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Is this CImg header available in the SDSoC? I tried to include CImg.h in SDSoC but it doesn't seems to exist.

Comment: What is SDSoC please? Grab the file `CImg.h` from the link in first line of my answer.